# Can a worn subframe bushing cause vibration at idle?

Tags: escape, motor-mounts

Apparently there are four mounts on my car.

[image]

1. Is the one I'm referring to in this question.
2. I know is good.
3. Seems to be in good condition. All the bolts are tight. But last time I checked wasn't supporting any weight.
4. I've never actually seen this mount. I don't know if it's good or bad. At one point this was the only mount out of the 4 that was holding any weight.

I think mount 1 needs to be replaced because it looks beat up, it's kind of soft to the touch, and I can see it's not actually supporting much of the engine's weight (if I press up and down on the engine I can see it move up and down on this mount. It's not so loose that I can move it about with my fingers but I don't think it's holding much engine weight).

[image]

My problem is I don't know where to get a replacement part. Advance Auto, Autozone, Oriely, Rock Auto, and Amazon don't seem to sell a "subframe bushing" or motor mount that looks anything like the part that I need. Heck, in the diagram they don't even have #1 pointing to the bushing, it's pointing to the metal connecting bracket that sits on the bushing. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09DVV5DHD) Amazon listing actually sells all the mounts (!) except the one I need.

So umm, do they sell just a subframe bushing (part 1)? I assume the car shaking at idle is caused by a bad motor mount situation and although part 1 isn't sold as a motor mount it's kind of acting that way, isn't it? I believe a new part 1 will fix my problem but I don't know where to get one.

Comment: Number 1 may not be there to support the engine, it may be there to stop the engine twisting as you accelerate.

Comment: It still looks bad, right? If it's not #1 then it must be #4 or #3.

Comment: I mean it can't be #3. After you bolt everything down there's not much you can do. It must be either #4 or #1.

Comment: + if it's there to support the engine as the car accelerates forward that, in my belief, lends credence to the idea that it is the cause of all this. in gear force is being applied to this bushing and that's when it vibrates. in neutral minimal force on this bushing and there is no vibration. i am more convinced than ever that this bushing is at fault.

Comment: The front motor mount (in your diagram mount #1) typically is filled with oil to absorb vibration at idle.

Comment: What is the year, make, model of your car?

Comment: 2002 Ford Escape

Comment: Partsgeek.com and CarsParts.com (neither are sponsors) have what look to be the correct front motor mount for your car.

Comment: I don't see it. It is called a motor mount, right? Why they only sell 3/4? https://www.carparts.com/search?q=engine_mount&vehicle[model]=Escape&vehicle[make]=Ford&vehicle[year]=2002 | https://www.partsgeek.com/catalog/2002/ford/escape/engine_mechanical/engine_mount.html

Comment: I found the official part anyways. It's called an engine support insulator. https://www.bluespringsfordparts.com/v-2002-ford-escape--xls--3-0l-v6-gas/engine--engine-and-trans-mounting

Comment: Can you add a video of the shaking engine?

Comment: Sure, here it is (btw running again. eh ...EHHH). I replaced mount 1 but it still shakes. Maybe I didn't tighten it down enough? The engine connects to the mount with one long 15mm bolt which MAYBE I didn't tighten down hard enough idk. Maybe it actually needs mount 4 which I have located and it wouldn't be the worst thing to replace. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FW7UfMFuhz0

Answer (score -1):

Try this link.  I searched on Google and this is what it returned.

https://www.google.com/search?q=front+motor+mount+2002+ford+escape&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS998US998&oq=front+motor+mount+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0i512j69i57j0i512l3j0i22i30l4.4918j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8